# Question about sentence structure and semicolons

Tags: punctuation, sentence, semicolons

Suppose the following sentence:

- When the sun comes in the morning; the sky is blue.

Are "When the sun comes in the morning" and "the sky is blue" two clauses of the sentence? So, is it correct to use a semicolon?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, those are both clauses, but it is not correct to use a semicolon. You must join them with a comma.

This is because those are not two independent clauses (essentially, two complete sentences).  Rather, the first one is governed by the conjunction *when*.

Comment: I was told that a sentence must contain a subject and verb phrase which I think are "sun" and "comes in the morning". So, what makes a complete sentence or independent clause exactly? Any way to recognize it? Thanks.

Comment: @user113212 It’s subordinate clause not an independent one because it is being governed by a subordinating conjunction.  If you did not have the *when* there, it would be two independent clauses, but the conjunction joins them together, putting the subordinate one under the main clause.

Comment: Does the sun ever "come"? Solar flares? Doesn't it usually & idiomatically _come up_ or _rise_ in the morning? (**NB: No boring remarks about astronomy, please. This is English usage, not astrophysics.**)

Comment: @BillFranke  Here comes the sun, doo doo doo doo, Here comes the sun, And I say It's alright

Comment: @StoneyB: True enough, but the structure is different from "When the sun comes". ?"Here comes up the sun" isn't idiomatic & probably isn't even grammatical except in an extreme case of poetic license. "Here rises the sun" might be reasonable in archaic dialogue & poetry, though. While one exception can disprove an absolute, it does more to "prove the rule (of thumb)" than to destroy its validity, methinks.